# Laravel 5.3, Cashier - Braintree - Single Charges

Tags: laravel-5.3, braintree, laravel-cashier

I followed the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/billing#single-charges) to implement the Cashier but I can't get it to work.

In short:

- made and migrated migrations
- added Billable to my `User.php` model
- added keys to my `.env`, referred to them in my `config/services.php` and added the SDK calls to my `AppServiceProvider.php`

If needed I can paste the code but it's the same (I checked but you never know) as in the docs.

Now if I try to run the

```
$user = User::find(2);
$response = $user->charge(15);
dd($response);
```

in my Controller I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in CustomerGateway.php line 567:
    expected customer id to be set

---

in CustomerGateway.php line 567
at CustomerGateway->_validateId(null) in CustomerGateway.php line 198
at CustomerGateway->find(null) in Customer.php line 106
at Customer::find(null) in Billable.php line 440
at User->asBraintreeCustomer() in Billable.php line 29
at User->charge('15') in MyController.php line 787
```

It seems to me that the error is here:

```
at Customer::find(null) in Billable.php line 440
```

which gives `null` for the `CustomerGateway`. So here is the code that gets called in line 29 of `Billable.php`

```
$customer = $this->asBraintreeCustomer();
public function asBraintreeCustomer()
{
    return BraintreeCustomer::find($this->braintree_id);
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I did `dd($this)` in `asBraintreeCustomer()` method and got my user. But the `braintree_id` attribute is `null`.
How do I populate these? 
Should I do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the Billable trait. Have been fixed on July 15th '17, you can read about the bug and the fix: https://github.com/laravel/cashier-braintree/commit/f0c133860d175a30676eedbab8d2345a59432910

You're in the way: the problem was with the `braintree_id` attribute being `null` when calling `$this->paymentMethod()`.

Just launch a `composer update` on your project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've moved on from this but I would need to get back to my code to see how I've fixed this as it was some time ago.